# BASH append line to earlier line if preceded by spaces

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool
            address 12.34.56.78
            state down
            address 13.34.56.78
            state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool
            address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool
            address 15.34.56.78
            state up
```

I wnat to output it so it looks like:

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 13.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool 15.34.56.78 state up
```

I've been trying with BASH, awk and sed, but nothing I have done has been able to give me the output I need for it.

One of the things I've tried:

Replace the 12 spaces at the beginning with an = then append to previous line if line starts with an =

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/            /=/' | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n=/ /;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

But that's not working...

Any help would be greatly received :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure that sed can do the trick.

Comment: Please show the bash,awk or sed attempts so we may assist in where you are having issues.

Comment: Updated.

I pasted in the first daft of the post, not the second *face palm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
/^[^[:blank:]+]/{                     # search for record/line does not start with blank
            if(s){print s; s=""}      # This is whenever state not found then print variable s
            p=$0                      # store record in varibale p   
            next                      # stop processing go to next line
}
{                             
      gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"")              # suppress starting space/tab char 
      s = s ? s OFS $0: p OFS $0      # if variable s has something then concatenate variable s with current record else variable p and current record
}
/state/{                              # if record has word state then 
      print s; s=""                   # print variable s and reset variable
}
END{                                  # end block
     if(s)print s                     # if s has something print s
}' file
```

**Oneliner**

```
$ awk '/^[^[:blank:]+]/{if(s){print s; s=""}p=$0; next}{gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"");s = s ? s OFS $0: p OFS $0; }/state/{print s; s=""}END{if(s)print s}' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat f
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool
            address 12.34.56.78
            state down
            address 13.34.56.78
            state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool
            address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool
            address 15.34.56.78
            state up
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '
/^[^[:blank:]+]/{
            if(s){print s; s=""}
            p=$0; 
            next
}
{
      gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"")
      s = s ? s OFS $0: p OFS $0 
}
/state/{
      print s; s=""
}
END{
     if(s)print s
}' f
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 13.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool address 15.34.56.78 state up
```

Comment: Akshay, that is brilliant!

I *think* I can see how it works :-)

Many thanks for your help!  And many thanks to everyone else that gave an answer to me!

Guess I'll need to dig out my books again!

Answer (score 1):

An easy option would be the following, combining a `sed` backreference and your `=` identifier:

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ])/=\1/g' file.txt |tr '\n' ' ' |tr '=' '\n' |sed -r 's/ +/ /g'
```

This would give the following output though, which might not exactly be what you were looking for, if I get your question correctly (since it doesn't start a new line with the corresponding `t2_` at the beginning for every address):

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down address 13.34.56.78 state down 
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78 
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool address 15.34.56.78 state up
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. `sed -r 's/^([^ ])/=\1/g'`: Put a `=` character at the beginning of every line NOT beginning with a space.

*Output:*

```
=t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool
            address 12.34.56.78
            state down
            address 13.34.56.78
            state down
=t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool
            address 14.34.56.78
=t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool
            address 15.34.56.78
            state up
```

2. `tr '\n' ' '`: Replace every line break with a space character.

*Output:*

```
=t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool             address 12.34.56.78             state down             address 13.34.56.78             state down =t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool             address 14.34.56.78 =t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool             address 15.34.56.78             state up
```

3. `tr '=' '\n'`: Replace every `=` character with a line break.

*Output:*

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool             address 12.34.56.78             state down             address 13.34.56.78             state down 
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool             address 14.34.56.78 
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool             address 15.34.56.78             state up
```

4. `sed -r 's/ +/ /g'`: Replace all consecuting space characters with a single space character.

*Output:*

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down address 13.34.56.78 state down 
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78 
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool address 15.34.56.78 state up
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```
$ cat f1
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool
            address 12.34.56.78
            state down
            address 13.34.56.78
            state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool
            address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool
            address 15.34.56.78
            state up    

$ echo $(cat f1) | sed 's/t2/\nt2/g'

t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down address 13.34.56.78 state down 
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78 
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool address 15.34.56.78 state up
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':a; $!N;s/\n[ ]\+/ /;ta;P;D' yourfile.txt
```

`$!N` append the next line if it is not the last.

`s\n[ ]\+/ /` replace all spaces after a new line with a single space.

`ta` if there was a match, go to label `:a`

`P`print the modified lines

`D` delete the old version of the lines

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
# for every new section (starting with non space)
   /^[^[:blank:]]/ {
# copy it to the hold buffer
      h
# delete the line (and go to next line)
      d
      }
# other line(s)
# add next line
   N
# add holding buffer to current line (with new line between)
   G
# reformat, removing new line followed by spaces and putitnging last line in front
   s/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)\^J[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)\^J\(.*\)/\3 \1 \2/
# print the resulting line
   ' YourFile
```

so in onliner POSIX

```
sed -e '/^[^[:blank:]]/{h;d' -e '};N;G;s/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)\^J[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)\^J\(.*\)/\3 \1 \2/' YourFile
```

Note: `\^J` is a real new line CTRL+V+J. `\n` avalaible for gawk and `\` with new line for POSIX is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it would be easier and more understandable with a simple awk script, like :

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    separator_address = "address" # Put what you want here
    line=""
    addr=""
    args=""
}
{
    if (substr($0, 1, 1) != " ") { # Start by a space
        if (addr != "") {
            print line" "addr" "args
        }
        line=$0
        addr = ""
        args = ""
        next # Nothing more to do here
    }
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0) # Remove spaces
    if (substr($0, 1, length(separator_address)) == separator_address) { 
        if (addr == "") { 
            addr = $0
        } else { 
            print line" "addr" "args
            addr = $0
            args = ""
        } 
    } else { 
        args = $0
    } 
}
END {
    if (addr != "") {
        print line" "addr" "args
    }
}' file.txt
```

Sed is indeed very powerful, but not really handy when it comes to multiple-lines treatment.
But as I don't really how you want the line splitted, I used a separator ("address"). If it's two line, you can use a flag instead of a separator (initialized at 0, +1 if you read some value beginning with space, print if it reaches 2, reinitialize after each print, for instance).

Result :

```
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 12.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_some_output_80_pool address 13.34.56.78 state down
t2_this_is_a_different_output_80_pool address 14.34.56.78
t2_this_is_another_output_80_pool 15.34.56.78 state up
```

Answer (score 0):

@try: One more approach too.

```
awk '{ORS=$0 ~ /^ +/?"":RS} {$1=$1} 1; END{print RS}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding explanation for code here too successfully now.

```
awk '{
ORS=           ##### Setting ORS(Output record separator) here, where output field separator is awk's default keyword whose default value is a new line.
$0 ~ /^ +/     ##### Checking if any record/line is starting from space here.
?              ##### Conditional operator here, which will execute it's following statements if above mentioned condition is TRUE.
""             ##### If above mentioned conditions is TRUE then setting ORS's value to NULL.
:              ##### : is a conditional operator here, which will execute the statements following it when conditions is FALSE.
RS}            ##### Setting ORS's value to RS(Record separator) whose default value will be a new line.
{$1=$1}        ##### Resetting the $1(first field) here, so that value of ORS could be reflected here.
1;             ##### Mentioning 1 here. awk works on condition then action method, so I am making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action here so by default print action will happen here.
END{print RS}  ##### in this block printing the RS(record separator)'s value here.
'  Input_file  ##### mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra new-line at the beginning, and none at the end, this short script would do:

```
awk '/^[^ ]/ { printf "\n" } $1=$1' ORS=' '
```

You can fix both issues by adding `NR>1` and `END { print "\n" }` respectively.